# Identify the number of columns in a query from SELECT statement string alone - python

Tags: python, sql, regex, cx-oracle

**Background**

I am writing a script to execute queries with python, and there are times that the select statement may not return any values, and I need to assume an empty result is zero. Because null results do not carry any column information, so I need to find the expected number of columns based on the select statement itself.

I was trying to accomplish this in the following way (please feel free to suggest an alternate approach)

Assume I have the following:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('YYYY-MM-DD', DATE), 'some,string info', numbers FROM some_table;
```

With my original attempt, I parsed out all the information between the SELECT and FROM keywords, return just the column inputs, and then I tried to count the number of commas:

```
q = """TO_CHAR('YYYY-MM-DD',DATE), 'some,string info', numbers"""
commas = q.count(',')
print 'number of commas = ', commas
```

> number of commas = 4

I was making the assumption that #commas + 1 = #columns, but the extra commas throughout renders that assumption useless.

---

**Question**

Can a regular expression be used to extract commas that are not enclosed by quotes or parentheses? Is there a simpler way to find the number of columns expected from SELECT statement?

Comment: I'm confused. This looks over-engineered as I understand your question. You just want to know whether or not you got any results from your query?

Comment: If a field has a Null entry, you'll still get back the same number of commas. In the case you get not results at all, it's easy to test for that.

Comment: It's not that the field has a null entry, but that there are no rows returned by the query. In that case, how can else can you count up the columns?

Comment: You don't. Your query either returns (a/some) results or it does not. Say you do `data = c.fetchall()` then you can can test whether it has results with `if data:`. If your query returns any result at all, each line will have the same number of commas because it contains the same number of fields, regardless of whether those fields are null (so counting ',' is completely pointless). If the query returns nothing, `if data:` is `False`.

Comment: Well, in sort of the way my example is formatted, I'm pull data grouped by Date. If there is no data available for that date, the query returns nothing, but I need to assume that they values in this case are all zero. That's why I need a way of pulling the number of columns outside of the results themselves. So i was exploring how to pull that information just from the query string

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You build the query string yourself, so you should know exactly how many fields you are requesting back. Why would you parse a query after you built it,  using regex? If you build it iteratively in the code, put a counter in that loop as you build it. If you write the query by hand, you already know exactly how many fields you expect.

Comment: That true. These are hand written queries, so we do know. The program I'm writing is really for metric reporting. Users can fill out a text file with all their metric queries (grouped by date). Because we can pull different amounts of information from different tables, the number of columns can vary. 

Main thing here is that I personally don't know the queries that are going to be used ahead of time, because it subject to each user. Maybe then it's as simple as having users fill out a list, where each value corresponds to the #columns for the respective query?

Comment: I'm not sure that I properly understand the issue, but I think calling `len()` on each line of the result will be more accurate than trying to count commas. `if not data:` will catch the case where the query returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can examine the cursor attribute called description. That will contain metadata about the columns, regardless of whether or not the query returns any data!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am no python expert, so leaving any python solutions to experts.

Through SQL, you can achieve what you want, although its quite tricky/hacky and ugly:

The idea is to create a dummy table and do a left join with your table:

```
create table dummy(dummy_value int);   // This needs to be done only once.

insert into dummy values(0);  // This needs to be done only once.

select YOUR_COLUMNS, dummy_value from (select dummy_value from dummy)dt LEFT OUTER JOIN YOUR_TABLE on 1=1;  // Modify your select queries like this/ Modify the script which creates query to add left outer join like this in all select queries
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b0531/1)

This is on assumption that you can make changes in query creation part.